# Bokeh time series plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, visualization, bokeh

I am trying to plot a time series value in Bokeh. I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
                    start_time                end_time  value
0  2017-06-16 18:15:34.714 2017-06-16 18:34:59.335      0
1  2017-06-16 18:34:59.335 2017-06-16 18:49:00.456      2
2  2017-06-16 18:49:00.456 2017-06-16 18:52:59.638      0
3  2017-06-16 18:52:59.638 2017-06-16 19:02:59.191      2
4  2017-06-16 19:02:59.191 2017-06-16 19:09:00.078      2
5  2017-06-16 19:09:00.078 2017-06-16 19:12:59.106      3
6  2017-06-16 19:12:59.106 2017-06-16 19:17:59.567      2
7  2017-06-16 19:17:59.567 2017-06-16 19:23:59.887      2
8  2017-06-16 19:23:59.887 2017-06-16 19:32:00.095      2
9  2017-06-16 19:32:00.095 2017-06-16 19:39:59.576      2
10 2017-06-16 19:39:59.576 2017-06-16 19:44:59.836      2
```

I want to make a horizontal line plot that has y-axis corresponding to value. The line should have different color based on the value column. The horizontal line should be representative of start-time and end-time as well.

I am playing around with bokeh plot but I am not able to do so. I tried resampling the time series as well. It would be very great if you could kindly help.

Comment: What is a "horizontal line plot?" Do you mean a [stepped line plot](https://www.anychart.com/chartopedia/chart-type/stepline-chart/)?

Comment: @bigreddot yes! thanks for letting me know its called stepped line plot. Thats what I want.

Comment: If you just wanted a single-color step line you could use `figure.step` but I am afraid there is not a simple way to vary the color of different step segments. I think you will have to specify individual segments and call the `segments` method